# ** (Mix) The database for PhoenixHerokuWsmoak.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: could not connect to server

Tags: phoenix-framework

** (Mix) The database for PhoenixHerokuWsmoak.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 2):

If you have this problem, Well, that's because Postgres isn't running locally. I'm not even sure it's installed. The easiest way to do that on a Mac is to grab **Postgres.app** from http://postgresapp.com and copy it to the `/Applications` folder.

Trying again:

```
$ mix​​ ​​ecto.create​
```

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have it installed without the proper user/pass to access it.